# Can't post with Perl's Net::Blogger

Tags: perl

I'm trying to automatically post to blogger using Perl's [Net::Blogger](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Blogger/) but it keeps returning false and not posting.  The main portion of my code looks like this:

```
use Net::Blogger;

my $blogger = Net::Blogger->new({
    debug    => 1,
    appkey   => '0123456789ABCDEF', # doesn't matter?
    blogid   => $blogid,
    username => $username,
    password => $password,
});

my $result = $blogger->newPost({
    postbody => \'<p>This is text</p><hr/><p><strong>Whee!</strong></p>',
    publish  => 1,
});

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($result);
```

Sure enough, $result is 0 and in checking the blog, nothing has been posted.  The error I'm getting when I enable debugging is:

```
Element '' can't be allowed in valid XML message. 
Died. at /Library/Perl/5.10.1/SOAP/Lite.pm line 1410.
```

What am I doing wrong?

If you can suggest an alternative to Net::Blogger, that would be fine.

*Update*: if I don't enable debugging, it hangs for quite a while when trying to post.

Answer (score 3):

I can understand your frustration, I don't like it when I try to use a CPAN module which is seductively named (i.e. looks like a good scratch for the itch) but is ultimately not useful.  However, Net::Blogger had its last update in 2006 so I think it would be incredible if it still worked as originally intended, given that blogger has been evolving over the years.

Per daxim's rec, I made a quick attempt to install Atompub on OS X via CPAN.pm, but failed due to a hard dependency on Perl::Critic, which won't install. I figure I know how to fix this but I'll need a better reason than this to go to the effort.

I saw this note in the Net::Blogger perldoc which if nothing else provides a hint on another module to try, for anyone who didn't feel like beating Atompub into submission:

> The Atom API
>
> In January 2004, Blogger announced
>   their support for the Atom API.
>
> As of this writing (version 0.87) this
>   package does not support the Atom API.
>   If you need to do things Atom-ish,
>   your best bet is to use the XML::Atom
>   package.

Comment: It's a shame XML::Atom is not documented, but it installs first try. I'll try to apply it to this problem today.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative as you requested: after all the different blogging APIs, a standard in the form of RFC 5023 emerged.

[Atompub](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Atompub/) works fine.

Comment: And that looks fantastic, but I can't find the atompub service URL for blogger. Are there any working examples you can point me to?

Comment: Found http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingPublicEntries on the BloggerDev discussion group.

Comment: daxim: yeah, I was already working off of that. The problem is that atompub starts with a service, but the URL is not clear to me. Every time I've tried to munge it to make it work, I've failed. I can sit down and try to read the entire spec and make this work, but I'm frustrated that Perl used to own the Web and I can't find a single working example of this anywhere. Only disconnected bits and pieces. What should be a five minute coding job is turning into hours of reading cryptic documentation.

Comment: Ovid: it's to give you the feeling for what it's like to work in most other languages most of the time :)

Answer (score 1):

I worked a bit with Net::Logger today and managed to publish an entry into Blogger, the problem is that only the body can be set (no Atom supported as virtualsue told).

Please take a look at my [Perl Posting to Blogger blues](http://the-dailynerd.blogspot.com/2012/02/perl-posting-to-blogger-blues.html) entry for some help.